# What is the probability that a 1 was sent, given that 1 was received?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have the following information:

> $0$ is sent with probability $0.3$
>
> $1$ is sent with probability $0.4$
>
> $2$ is sent with probability $0.3$
>
> Due to noise, $0$ is changed to $1$ during transmission with probability $0.2$
>
> Due to noise, $0$ is changed to $2$ during transmission with probability $0.1$
>
> Due to noise, $1$ is changed to $0$ during transmission with probability $0.2$
>
> Due to noise, $1$ is changed to $2$ during transmission with probability $0.1$
>
> Due to noise, $2$ is changed to $0$ during transmission with probability $0.2$
>
> Due to noise, $2$ is changed to $1$ during transmission with probability $0.1$

Let A - the event that $\text{1 is received}$,

B - the event that $\text{1 is sent}$

I must find $P(B|A)$:

$$P(B|A) = \frac{P(A|B)P(B)}{P(A)}$$

$P(B)$ = 0.4

---

$P(A|B)$ = P(1 is sent) $\times$ P(1 **does not change**)

P(1 **does not change**) = [1 - P(1 becomes 0)]$\times$[1 - P(1 becomes 2)] (right?)

(1-0.2)(1-0.1) = 0.72

P(1 is sent) $\times$ 0.72 = (0.4)(0.72) = 0.288

---

P(A) = P(1 is sent and it stays 1) + P(0 is sent and it changes to 1) + P(2 is sent and it changes to 1)

P(A) = 0.288 + (0.3)(0.2) + (0.3)(0.1) = 0.378

---

Final answer:
$$\frac{0.288 \times 0.4}{0.378} = 0.30$$

---

Has this been done correctly?

Comment: @miracle173, I did that now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's start out simply:

The odds of a 0 being sent are 0.3.  The odds of a 1 being sent are 0.4.  The odds of a 2 being sent are 0.3.

The odds of a 1 being received *given that a 0 was sent* are 0.2.  Out of the total sample space, that's odds of 0.3 * 0.2 = 0.06.

Likewise, odds of a 2 being sent and a 1 being received (out of total sample space) is 0.3 * 0.1 = 0.03.

Total odds (out of total sample space) of a 1 being received when *something else* was sent is then 0.03 + 0.06 = 0.09.

Odds of a 1 being sent *and* received is 0.4 * 0.7 = 0.28.  (Note: *Given that a 1 was sent,* odds of a 0 being received are 0.2.  Given that a 1 was sent, odds of a 2 being received are 0.1.  Thus, given that a 1 was sent, odds of a 1 being received are 0.7.)

So *given that a 1 was received,* the odds that it was actually a 1 that was sent are 0.28 / (0.28 + 0.09) = 0.28 / 0.37 = 28/37 $\approx$ 0.757.

---

You can visualize the total sample space, proportionately, like so:

[image]

With *that* picture, all you have to do is count squares to see that the answer is 28/37.  :)

Comment: I had you to "Odds of a 1 being sent and received is 0.4 * 0.7 = 0.28."

Comment: Where did you get the 0.7

Comment: @VeeshaDawg, see update.

Comment: Okay I see, thanks! :D

Comment: Amazing image, thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 3):

Let $S=k$ be the event that $k$ was sent and let $R=k$ be the event that
$k$ was received.

You want to compute $P[S=1|R=1] = {P[S=1 \text{ and } R=1] \over P[R=1]}$.

$P[R=1] = \sum_k P[R=1|S=k] P[S=k] = 0.3 \times 0.2 + 0.4 \times 0.7 + 0.3 \times 0.1 $.

$P[S=1 \text{ and } R=1]  = P[R=1|S=1] P[S=1] = 0.4 \times 0.7$.

Hence $P[S=1|R=1] = {28 \over 37}$.

Comment: What I don't understand is that.. If we are calculating the probability that 1 stays at 1 .. thats equal to to the probability that 1 does not turn to 2 and that 1 does not turn to 0

Comment: woudnt that be (1-0.1)(1-0.2)?

Comment: No, you are looking at the probability that a one was sent given that one was received. There are only three possibilities to look at, $k$ was sent and $1$ received for $k=0,1,2$.

Comment: I believe k = 0,1,2

Comment: and yes, there are 3 possibilities to look at, so the other two must be false, so why are you adding 0.1 and 0.2

Comment: You are given $P[0|1|$ and $P[2|1]$ but not $P[1|1]$ so you need to compute $P[1|1] = 1-P[0|1|- P[2|1|$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I didnt downvote, i upvoted to make it 0, im not sure who did

Comment: Let me check, I quite easily could have made a mistake.

Comment: My answer is incorrect, I need to fix it.

Comment: The original downvote was justified.

Comment: Mine was the downvote.  :)  I had to double-check my work because I thought it must be wrong if it disagreed with a 100K-rep user's answer.  I've taken the downvote off now, of course.

Comment: @Wildcard: I make lots of mistakes, I construct by correction... The 100K just represents longevity, procrastination & lots of wine.

Answer (score 0):

By letting $S,R$ be the value Sent and Received, then we are given, and can immediately infer, that: $$\begin{align}\newcommand{\P}{\operatorname {\mathsf P}}
&\P(S{=}0)=0.3, \P(S{=}1)=0.4, \P(S{=}2)=0.3 \\
&\P(R{=}1\mid S{=}0)=0.2, \P(R{=}2\mid S{=}0)=0.1 &\implies \P(R{=}0\mid S{=}0)=0.7 \\ 
&\P(R{=}0\mid S{=}1)=0.2, \P(R{=}2\mid S{=}1)=0.1 &\implies \P(R{=}1\mid S{=}1)=0.7 \\ 
&\P(R{=}0\mid S{=}2)=0.2, \P(R{=}1\mid S{=}2)=0.1 &\implies \P(R{=}2\mid S{=}2)=0.7 \\ 
\end{align}$$

Then by Bayes' Rule, with the Law of Total Probability: $$\P(S{=}1\mid R{=}1) = \dfrac{\P(R{=}1\mid S{=}1)\P(S{=}1)}{\P(R{=}1\mid S{=}0)\P(S{=}0){+}\P(R{=}1\mid S{=}1)\P(S{=}1){+}\P(R{=}1\mid S{=}2)\P(S{=}2)}$$

The rest is just substitution of values.

---

Why does $\P(R{=}1\mid S{=}1)=0.7$ and so forth?   It is because by the definition of probability (which is also applicable to conditional probabilities): $$\P(R{=}0\mid S{=}1)+\P(R{=}1\mid S{=}1)+\P(R{=}2\mid S{=}1)~=~1 \\[2ex] \therefore~\P(R{=}1\mid S{=}1)~=~1-0.1-0.2$$

Answer (score 0):

P(1 **does not change**) = [1 - P(1 becomes 0)]$\times$[1 - P(1 becomes 2)] (right?)

This assumes that P(1 becomes 0) and P(1 becomes 2) are independent events.

Consider what happens if 1 is transformed to 0 with probability 0.5, and 1 is transformed to 2 with probability 0.5 - what is the probability that 1 is correctly received?

The correct calculation is
P(1 **does not change**) = 1 - [(P(1 becomes 0) + P(1 becomes 2)]

This because received 1 and received 2 are mutually exlusive.